# Clarity about functioning of SequenceMatcher.ratio() function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, difflib

I am confused on how SequenceMatcher.ratio() work. After searching on the Internet, I understand the formula for computing the ratio is:

Ratio = 2.0 * M / T

where

M = number of matches

T = total number of elements in both sequence

I tried inputing different values in the function but I got some unexpected answers during some scenarios

The values I tried:

```
>>> SequenceMatcher(None, "rain","nrai").ratio(). 
0.75
```

Using the Ratio formula in above situation should give an answer 1.0

```
M = 4 (as all the letters match)
T = 8 (both words are of 4 letters)
Ratio = 2.0 * 4 / 8
Ratio = 8/8 = 1.0
```

I am struggling to understand why is it behaving this way? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 matches:
Given "rain" "nrai"

```
"ra"
"ai"
"rai"

2 * 3 / 8 = 0.75
```

You are not matching whether the letter exists on both sequences, you are matching sequence (group) of the letters.

1.0 is returned only when the sequences are EXACT

Comment: Thanks for your response, It was really helpful. Although, when I was playing around with SequenceMatcher considering the logic you just explained, I encountered another ambiguity:                                                                                                                             SequenceMatcher(None, "rain","niar").ratio()     The answer was : 0.25                              I am confused which were the two matches that resulted the answer 0.25

Comment: Yeah that's quite a weird one, it should be 0 following the common sense logic. I see there that the 'number of matches' is somewhat a max of (1,actualMatches) so it doesn't divide by zero when you do not have any matches, quite weird because in the scenario when you have one match it would produce the same output. Weird indeed.

Comment: Ohh! Thanks again.